# Arrange numbers and operators to piano-keys

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-theory, music

[image]

Let a # b = a*10 + b
Example :

```
5 # 5 = 55
9.5 # 3 = 98
```

Arrange numbers 1 to 7 to each piano's-white-keys. 
 
Then arrange operators (+,-,x,/, and #) to each piano's-black-keys. 
Operation is done from left to right.

> (((((C op1 D) op2 EF) op3 G) op4 A) op5 B)

The result **must be 3000**.

Example: 
[image]

(((((3/6) + 14) * 7) - 2) # 5) = 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline\\C&\text{op1}&D&\text{op2}&E&F&\text{op3}&G&\text{op4}&A&\text{op5}&B\\\hline5&/&2&+&7&3&\#&1&-&6&×&4\\\hline\end{array}$$
>
>  (((((5/2)+73)#1)-6)×4) → ((((((5/2)+73)*10)+1)-6)*4) = 3000